# Correct way to get an instance of CodeDomProvider

Tags: c#, mono

```
var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

or 

var codeProvider = new CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");
```

They appear to do the same thing which is confusing me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();` where `CSharp` is the known language prior to runtime.

See note below on [CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yzxs14d.aspx) Method reference:

> This method is most commonly used to
>   create an instance of a code provider
>   in an application that may optionally
>   use one of several providers.
>   CreateProvider allows you to specify
>   at run time the code provider you wish
>   to instantiate. If you know at design
>   time which code provider is to be
>   used, you should create an instance of
>   that code provider rather than use the
>   CreateProvider method.

Answer (score 0):

I think both CSharpCodeProvider and CodeDomProvider.CreatProvider are pointing to the same object instantiation, so it doesn't matter which one you use.